# angular9 with primeng fullcalendar throws errors: Cannot find namespace 'FullCalendarVDom'. and 'Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib'

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, primeng

I use primeng p-fullcalendar in my angular app.

I get this error in command-line:
'Cannot find namespace 'FullCalendarVDom'

and in browser:
'Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin.'

my code:

```
import { FullCalendar } from 'primeng/fullcalendar';
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
```

```
@ViewChild('calendar', { static: true }) private calendar: FullCalendar;
```

in c'tor:

```
 this.events = [{
   "title": "Conference",
   "start": "2016-01-11",
   "end": "2016-01-13"
 }];
 this.options = {
   plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
   defaultDate: '2017-02-01',
   header: {
     left: 'prev,next',
     center: 'title',
     right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   }
```

I added these imports according to preview answers, but it did not help.

What I missed?

Answer (score 4):

Primeng working with FullCalendar 4.1, instead of instaling latest version of FullCalendar try to install v4.1.

```
npm i @fullcalendar/core@4.1.0
npm i @fullcalendar/interaction@4.1.0
npm i @fullcalendar/daygrid@4.1.0
npm i @fullcalendar/timegrid@4.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same problem with my primeNG v12 + Angular v12 setup. Did a little research and finally able to build it with FullCalendar version 5.8 successfully.

*In a nutshell*; i've changed the declaration of FullCalendar in html template to work with @fullcalendar/angular package as stated in this issue **#10451**: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/96fc1ced182a78eef87781018a65d1e1cfb51307

Here's the steps:

- Installed the **@fullcalendar/angular** package.
- Changed this

```
<p-fullCalendar [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>
```

To this

```
<full-calendar [options]="options"></full-calendar>
```

- Finally made the appropriate changes in app.module.ts file to make newly added html tag to work.

```
import {FullCalendarModule} from '@fullcalendar/angular';
@NgModule({
...
imports: [FullCalendarModule]
...
})
```