# How do I properly install Fullcalendar from PrimeNg in Angular project?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

So I've done everything according to the docs [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/fullcalendar). As soon as I add the plugin imports I get the following error:

Error: node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/vdom.d.ts:2:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FullCalendarVDom'.

I have searched the web for answers but nothing helped me.  Below is excerpts from my project that  I think might be relevant in solving my problem.

package.json

```
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.4",
    
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.7.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.7.2",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.7.2",
```

angular.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "ostobuddy-dashboard-angular": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss",
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:class": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:directive": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:guard": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:interceptor": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:module": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:service": {
                    "skipTests": true
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/global-zone",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
                            "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
                            "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
                            "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
                            "src/styles.scss",
                            "node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.css",
                            "node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.css",
                            "node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"
                        ]
                    },
```

my.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PodEditComponent, PodsTableComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FullCalendarModule
  ]
})
```

my.component.ts (this is the part throwing the error)

```
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
```

Any support would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did you run these commands ?

`npm install @fullcalendar/daygrid --save


npm install @fullcalendar/timegrid --save


npm install @fullcalendar/interaction --save`

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be import { ... } from ....? Maybe the loading of the whole file is throwing it off

Comment: I did run those commands. I ran it twice actually. I followed the docs exactly. What else can you think about?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653667/angular9-with-primeng-fullcalendar-throws-errors-cannot-find-namespace-fullcal) is the solution to my question.